# Why Async Method always blocking thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method async like this:

```
public static async Task<bool> SendMailAsync(){
...something
}
```

This method is very long time to return result.

I have other method like this:

```
public async Task<string> ThisIsController(){
Task<bool> result = SendMailAsync();
OtherMethod1();
OtherMethod2();
....
}
```

I'm not use await in result. But "ThisIsController" always wait result return then run OtherMethod1(), OtherMethod2?
Thank you

Update1:
Full code of SendMailAsync():

```
public static async Task<bool> SendMailAsync(List<string> listEmail, string subject, string body)
    {
        try
        {
            var emailsPerMin = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailsPerMin"]
                .ToString());
            for (int i = 1; i <= System.Math.Ceiling(listEmail.Count * 1.0 / emailsPerMin); i++)
            {

                List<string> sendingList = listEmail.Skip((i - 1) * emailsPerMin).Take(emailsPerMin).ToList();
                foreach (var email in sendingList)
                {
                    MailHelper.SendMail(email, subject, body);
                    Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how this method is `async`.

Comment: I just updated my code. Sorry :). Hope you help

Comment: Please give a code for your SendMailAsync

Comment: I updated the method. Thank you

Comment: Your MailHelper.SendMail should be async also. As per the name (no Begin/End) I suspect it is blocker.

Comment: I tried async MailHelper.SendMail. But it's not working

Comment: adding async keyword doesn't make your method asynchronous. What it make is that inside you will use await and other asynchronous methods.

Comment: If i understand it correclty, you want SendMailAsync to run in background?

Comment: Yes. I wanna SendMailAsync run in background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the `async` method **does not** (by itself) make code asynchronous. Async code is *hard* - all that the `async` modifier does is enable the `await` keyword (and enable some compiler magic about the return type). If the method doesn't actually do anything asynchronous, it *won't be asynchronous*. In particular:

- if a method doesn't `await`: it won't really be asynchronous in the `async` sense

  - (minor caveat there: if a method *isn't* marked `async`, and simply `return`s a `Task[<T>]` from *another* method, then it might *expose* an asynchronous behaviour)
- if a method *does* `await`, but all of the things being awaited always actually completed synchronously: it isn't truly asynchornous

In this case, it is the first bullet. There is no `await` in the code. In fact, the compiler should already be giving you a warning about this:

> `Warning  CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.`

Even if a method returns `Task[<T>]` (or some other awaitable pattern): if it isn't *actually* asynchronous (because of either of the bullets above): it will run to completion **before** it returns to the caller; and when it does so, it will be known as already complete.

---

For this code to be asynchronous, *something it does* (presumably the send) would need to be asynchronous. Perhaps:

```
foreach (var email in sendingList)
{
    await MailHelper.SendMailAsync(email, subject, body);
    await Task.Delay(60 * 1000);
}
```

Note; if your `MailHelper` doesn't have an `async` API, you *could* also make it asynchronous just by making the *delay* asynchronous:

```
foreach (var email in sendingList)
{
    MailHelper.SendMail(email, subject, body);
    await Task.Delay(60 * 1000);
}
```

Final thought: hiding exception details is almost always bad.

Comment: @miken btw - idea: if you move the `Task.Delay` to **above** the `SendMail`, then you get two nice things: the "sync" part of the code returns *before* trying to send the first mail (so all the mail sends happen on the worker context), and: there is no unnecessary delay *after* the last item has sent

Answer (score 3):

SendMailAsync will run synchronously until first await block inside.

Marking method as "async" doesn't actually make it magically to run asynchronously. You have to use await inside that method

Your code is synchronous, to run it in another thread without changing signature or code in your SendMailAsync you can use. But ideally you should rewrite SendMailAsync to use async API of MailSender

```
var resultTask = Task.Run(async () => await SendMailAsync());
OtherMethod1();
OtherMethod2();
var result = await resultTask;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you await a OtherMethod1() they will wait till the Method is finished, then he will execute OtherMethod2(). But if u dont await it could be that Method1 is not finished and Method2 will start. This depends on what is inside in Method1 and 2.

Comment: I know it. But OtherMenthod1() not start ulti SendEmailAsync () finished :(

Comment: This is because your SendMailAsync method itself is 100% synchronous

Comment: @dlxeon: Any solution for this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are several background jobs processing library out there. I have used hangfire for some of my projects.

But if you want to make this simple, you can use something built-in inside asp.net.

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((ct) =>
{
     SendMailAsync();
});

OtherMethod1();
OtherMethod2();
```

Make sure you add reference to System.Web.Hosting

You do not need SendMailAsync() to return a Task since you will not be awaiting on something. Just let the sending of email code run in background.